# How to make ssh tunneling on Ubuntu subsystem (Windows 10)?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

When I want to use this command in Ubuntu ( Windows 10 subsystem ) for using VNCserver

```
ssh -L 5901:127.0.0.1:5901 -N -f -l username server_ip_address
```

I see this error message:

```
unknown option -- L
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
usage: sshd [-46DdeiqTt] [-b bits] [-C connection_spec] [-c host_cert_file]
            [-E log_file] [-f config_file] [-g login_grace_time]
            [-h host_key_file] [-k key_gen_time] [-o option] [-p port]
            [-u len]
```

ssh version show this message:

```
root@win:~# ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: `ssh -V` should have been `OpenSSH_7.2p2 ...` like in the error message. Add the output of `type -a ssh`, please.

Comment: `usage: sshd ...` Somehow you're not running the usual ssh command line utility. Somehow the sshd server program has gotten linked to the ssh name, or you're running a script that tries to launch sshd, or something like that.

Comment: @muru output is: ssh is /usr/bin/ssh